# Line chart in Dash Plotly is inconsistent when a record does not have data for a specific month

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The dataframe contains the data as follows:

[image]

I do the sum of the number of months(meses) per professional, however, there is a professional that in the month of June has no record and with that the chart is with the month of June in the last month which would be December(Dez).

[image]

When I remove the professional 'Heitor' who does not have the June record, the graph is correct.

[image]

Is it possible to resolve graphically or is it only possible if I create several columns in the dataframe for the months of January to December with the amounts of each month?

Comment: Change the x-axis type to category and specify a list of month names from January to December. See the reference for [more information](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#controlling-the-category-order-with-plotly-express).

Comment: @r-beginners - Exactly that, I had not read that reference documentation, thank you very much.